# How to add a label to a MapControl in a UWP App

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, uwp

I am developing an Universal App (Windows 10). I am adding a set of `MapPolygons` to a map control.

I can not find a way to add text to a `MapPolygon`. When I try to extend the class, I get a 'class sealed error'. How can I add text in the middle of each `MapPolygon`?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps;

namespace MyApp.Models
{
    class MapGrid: MapPolygon
    {
        string Label { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The error is:

> 'MapGrid' cannot derive from sealed type 'MapPolygon'

Comment: Can you add a code sample and the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Get the coordinates of the center of the polygon and add to map these coordinates TextBlock

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add a text to a specific location on your map, you can use the MapIcon control. just change the default image in the map icon to a transparent or empty image (in the sample it is a CustomIcon.png in Assets).

```
        Geopoint myPoint = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 50, Longitude = 11 });
                   MapIcon myPOI = new MapIcon {Location = myPoint, NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1.0), Title = "Here I am", ZIndex = 0 };
        myPOI.Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/CustomIcon.png"));
        MapItemsControl test = new MapItemsControl();


        myMap.MapElements.Add(myPOI);
        myMap.Center = myPoint;
        myMap.ZoomLevel = 10;
```

XAML

```
<Maps:MapControl x:Name="myMap"/>
```